# Importing Python module from string using Python3 C API

Tags: python, c

There's an excellent answer for the same question for Python 2: [Importing module from string in the Python C API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39808521/importing-module-from-string-in-the-python-c-api)

I tried that in Python3 but it seems that this doesn't work anymore. The code compiles but when I try to do `print(blah)` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
NameError: name 'blah' is not defined
```

Does anyone know what could have changed?

Comment: This is far from perfect but I've found a method to make this work: I imported dict created this way into builtins: `PyDict_SetItemString(builtins, "dict", dict);` and then transformed it into namespace using `argparse.Namespace`.